# Alien crashes at house, lives with family

Tags: story-identification, aliens

It was about an alien who crash landed on Earth and finds himself living with the family whose house he had crashed at. I remember the alien was operated by practical effects. It's not ALF or Aliens in the Family. It was one alien, cute not scary, and I think he lived in the living room.
It came on sometime in the 1990's on ABC, CBS or NBC. I believe it only lasted one season as it didn't do very well.

I've been trying many different searches and am coming up empty. Perhaps you fine folks can help me. I've asked around but no one seems to know. I would love to go back and watch some episodes on YouTube, I just can't remember the show title. Anyone have any idea what this show could be?

Comment: "enjoyed as a kid" -  is there a year (or range of years) you can give us ?

Comment: This totally sounds like ALF

Comment: Also reminds me of [*My Favourite Martian*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056775/), but that's way too old

Comment: Describing the alien would be helpful; "cute" is subjective and doesn't help if we manage to find an image.  At best, excluding ALF, best I can come up with is Meego, but I don't think an alien Bronson Pinchot qualifies as "cute".

Comment: Kind of sounds like _E.T._ to me, except that was obviously not a series.

Comment: How about "Mork & Mindy," starring Robin Williams & Pam Dawber? (earlier 1978-1982, and 4 seasons, though)

Comment: Was it primarily a family sitcom or what?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't Aliens in the Family?  The time frame fits (1996) and it lasted one season. It was produced by the Jim Henson production team, so that would be practical effects.

Comment: Sounds a bit like "Mike and Angelo". I'm not sure if Angelo, the alien, did crash-land in the family house or if he just landed normally. He did stay with the family. As for "cute alien" - he looked exactly like a human. The main stumbling block is that it was a British series, but maybe an (unsuccessful) attempt was made to screen it in the USA? If so, though, I've never heard of one.